# Circular header dependency caused by inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, circular-dependency

I have two C++ header/source files. In `Object.h`:

```
#include "Exception.h"

class SomeException : public Exception {};

class Object {
public:
    someFoo() {
        throw SomeException();
    }
};
```

And in `Exception.h`:

```
#include <exception>
#include "Object.h"

class Exception : public Object, public std::exception {
    // ...
};
```

The "include once" macro is omitted. The code would not be compiled, because   one of `Object` or `Exception` will become unknown, so I add a forward declaration header file `common.h`:

```
class Object;
class Exception;
```

And change `#include` lines to `#include "common.h"`. This skill works for arguments' and returning types, but it fails on inheritance, because C++ refuses to derive an incomplete base class. How to solve it?

Comment: This can be solved by moving someFoo to .cpp file, but looks like incorrect design. How can Object throw SomeException, it should not know anything about it.

Comment: By moving SomeException to Exception.h and moving someFoo to cpp file and removing inclusion of Exception.h from Object.h you can solve the problem

Comment: I've added a new answer to the duplicate. You can use this technique to solve your problem.